# What do you call this in Objective c and Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, mobile

Hi I am new in iOS development. Just want to ask what do you call these in objective-c and swift

```
^(NSArray *name){

// code here/ For loop/

};
```

Thank you very much for your response :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the code of Objective-C.

Its known as Blocks in Objective-C.
In swift similar approach is implemented using Closure.

Just search for **`Blocks in Objective-C`** and **`Closure in Swift`**.

Comment: Hi Thank you very much for your answer :)